# is it possible to use if-else statements in mocha's it() function individually?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, if-statement, conditional-statements, mocha.js

I recently started with mocha and wanted to know if we could use if else statements for conditional testing. I want to be able to use conditions in ever it() function in order to put assertions on Json data received in response to that getprojection() function call.

I have posted a code as an example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('chai').should();
// var projection = require('');
var projectionsTest = require('./getProjection')



    describe("Annual Tax Projection", function () {
        describe("Current Year Tax - #2018", function () {
            it("should return correct taxable Income", function (done) {
                projectionsTest.getProjection('params', 'params', function (projections) {
                    if (grossIncome <= deductions){
                        assert.deepEqual(projections[2018].taxableIncome, 0)
                    }else throw new Error("There is something wrong with tax calculation")
                    done(Error);
                });
            });
            it("should check federal tax is calculated correctly", function (done) {
                projectionsTest.getProjection('params', 'params', function (projections) {
                    if (taxableIncome === 0 || taxBracket ===10){
                        assert.deepEqual(projections[2018]. )
                    }else
                    done(Error);
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: If it works, you can. Should you? No, because a unit test, IMO, should only test a single path through the code.

Comment: okay, so is that fine if i just validate the given object property in Json by comparing it with expected results? without having if-else conditions?

Comment: I have no idea what your code does, but if the `getProjection` function returns an object of known shape and values for a given set of arguments, that’s what I would test.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks Man!! I really appreciate it.